# The power method/ iteration

Tags: linear-algebra

What are the advantages and disadvantages of using the power method/ iteration to calculate eigenvalues and eigenvectors?

Comment: The most glaringly opvious advantage would be that it is really easy to implement. Disadvantages include that it might be slow, and it can in its most naive form only compute the largest eigenvalue of a matrix. Also, it gets into trouble if the largest eigenvalue corresponds to an eigenspace with dimension more than $1$, since it only finds you _one_ approximate eigenvector.

Comment: Application: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_matrix

Comment: Ive been reading that this method can be altered to find other eigenvalues such as the smallest or second largest